# How to use google-api-php-client on laravel 5.6 when there is no namespace

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Sorry if this is a repeat but the few close questions I have found have not worked for me. I am a Laravel newbie. I am trying to use the github library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client with laravel 5.6 framework.

I installed the api by running:

composer require google/apiclient:^2.0

My composer.json looks correct since it includes:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
```

I have run composer update.  I can see the Google folder in my Vendor's folder.

The github readme for this then says to add the autoloader include.  However, this is not the way we do it for Laravel from my understanding. I have found that the Google_Client class has no namespace, so I don't know how to add it properly to the app.php file.  Or to use it within the controller I want to. When I try to create a new Google_Client within the controller, it says it can't be found.  If I try to 'use' it, I don't know what path to give it without the namespace present.

**Editing to add more information for some of the comments below:**

I run 'composer require google/apiclient:^2.0

The output:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/sageAnalytics$ composer require google/apiclient:^2.0 ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Package operations: 10 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (2.0.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing firebase/php-jwt (v5.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing google/apiclient-services (v0.53): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing google/auth (v1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing google/apiclient (v2.2.1): Loading from cache phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-libsodium (SSH2/SFTP can make use of some algorithms provided by the libsodium-php extension.) phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-mcrypt (Install the Mcrypt extension in order to speed up a few other cryptographic operations.) phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-gmp (Install the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension in order to speed up arbitrary precision integer arithmetic operations.) google/apiclient suggests installing cache/filesystem-adapter (For caching certs and tokens (using Google_Client::setCache)) Writing lock file Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy Discovered Package: laravel/scout Discovered Package: laravel/tinker Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Its not one of the packages it discovered - Im thinking it should be.  My composer.json file looks like:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

When I run my program and call on new Google_Client I see

[image]

So Im missing something in getting it to be discovered by the autoloader.
Running the command 'composer dumpautoload' gives me:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/sageAnalytics$ composer dumpautoload
```

Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover
>   Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
>   Discovered Package: laravel/scout
>   Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
>   Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
>   Package manifest generated successfully.

So again there is no mention of package google/apiclient.  How do I get it to be found?

Comment: delete the `vendor` directory and run `composer install`, probably something went wrong when you modified the autoload classmap array

Comment: My pleasure. Feel free to accept you own answer so others know that it's solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was posted in the comments at the top for the first possible answer by @Razor.  I had messed up the project in some way most likely by messing with the autoload in composer.json.  I deleted the Vendor folder completely and re-ran composer install.  All works now.

Answer (score 18):

If a class is not in any namespace, you can reference from inside a namespace by prefixing it with a leading `\`, as in `$foo = new \Google_Client;`

Meanwhile, the string you specify in a `use` statement isn't a "path" as such, it's just the "fully-qualified class name", that is, the class name with its namespace included on the front. So for a class in no namespace, it's just the name, `use Google_Client;`

Comment: Ok, good info, but how does my project know where to find it then?  Right now I get the error Class 'Google_Client' not found.  Normally I would add it to the app.php within the config folder, but don't know how that would look without the namespace.

Comment: @JanelleThornContreras If the Composer package has been defined properly, then it should be available the same way any other Composer dependency is, via the autoloader.

Comment: Thats pretty much what my question is - how do I define it properly?  I have also tried adding "google/apiclient" to the autoload classmap array  but it causes an error - that it does not appear to be a file nor a folder.

Comment: Laravel already includes the autoloader, all you have to do is execute `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0`, run `composer dumpautoload` if you still have any issues.

Comment: I've added a lot more information - @Razor - just showing results from doing a simple composer require google/apiclient:^2.0 and also a composer dumpautoload.  Thank you for your replies all!  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

check the file composer.json

and add "vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google" in classmap array if not exist.

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google"
        ]
}
```

and run `composer dump-autoload`

No need of `use` or `require_once` statement.

the autoload array in composer.json makes ready all the files for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working in Laravel, there is probably a bit of extra handiwork required to register the google api classes within your services. I found this https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient, which might help you find a little bit more detail into installing a google api package that manages it specifically aimed at laravel.

Comment: Ya, I tried those steps as well already - didn't work.  It has a namespace so it was easy to get the class found.  Also thought of actually using it.  However there isn't a lot of documentation on it - not even sure if it is hitting google api v3 or v2.  Need v3